# How to use date_default_timezone_set() function and +1 day to the date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a form that enter a set of dates and the dates will be used for mysql queries. The date has to be `$date` +1 day when used with mysql query. It works fine except the server returns a warning about using `date_default_timezone_set()`.

```
//$date is date captured from an input form
$selected_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date . "+1 days"));
```

Error message received

> Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
>   You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
>   In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning,
>   you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.
>   We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

How can I use `date_default_timezone_set()` function and add one day to the date selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default utc timezone by adding one line. As system time may vary you can define default utc time and create or edit the date

```
 date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
 $selected_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date . "+1 days"));
```